# ¿Cómo hacer un COUNT sobre otro COUNT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos de productos y ventas.

Puedo hacer una consulta para sacar cuántos productos se vendieron el día X, de modo que sería

```
   SELECT fecha_venta, COUNT(*) as prods FROM productos GROUP BY fecha_venta
```

Esto me daría una consulta así

> 1 - 2015-07-08 - 9 prods
> 2 - 2015-08-09 - 2 prods
> 3 - 2015-08-10 - 9 prods
> 4 - 2015-08-11 - 7 prods
> 5 - 2015-08-12 - 2 prods
> 6 - 2015-08-13 - 9 prods

Bien, querría saber cómo se formularía la consulta para que el resultado quedara de esta manera:

> 3 días 9 productos  (1)
>
> 2 días 2 productos  (2)
>
> 1 día  7 productos  (3)

El resultado sale de la primera consulta:

> (1) - fila 1, 3 y 6 - esos 3 días se vendieron 9 productos
>
> (2) - fila 2 y 5 - esos 2 días se vendieron 2 productos
>
> (3) - fila 4 - ese día se vendieron 7 productos

Comment: Hola Yuri, necesitas incluir un ejemplo completo y verificable del problema al que te enfrentas y de ser posible incluye la parte relevante del o de los errores que obtengas. Sigue [esta guía](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que tu pregunta cumpla con los requisitos de calidad de la comunidad.

Comment: Pero esos días son por diferentes semanas o algo así, o son días especifico de la semana.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales He reformulado la pregunta para que quede más claro.

Comment: @Yuri La pregunta sigue sin ser clara. Lo que entiendo es mostrar el total vendido al día? 

Ej. 

Al 1er día se han vendido 19
Al 2do día se han vendido 50
Al 3er día se han vendido 60

?

Comment: ¿Quieres el número de filas,  o la cantidad de días transcurridos desde el una fecha (ej. primero del mes)? O es otra cosa?

Comment: @iBet7o He vuelto a editar. A ver si me aclaro: Es una especie de agrupación de contadores, quiero que me cuente cuántas veces ha contado que se han vendido x productos.

Comment: el ejemplo que porpocionas lo has realizado a conciencia? o sea si tomamos los valores de la primer lista donde pones fechas cual seria el dia 1? porque no veo ninguno la relacion. la verdad veo dificil de lograr lo que planteas porque ese concepto de dias que proporcionas esta algo raro

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ,rnd ,iBet7o ,toledano ,PedroMiguelPimientoMorales he editado la pregunta ya que sí entendí lo que el usuario preguntava. A ver si ahora está más claro :)

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que te refieres a una segunda agrupación.

Eso puedes hacerlo usando tu consulta como "tabla" de otra consulta, algo así como:

```
SELECT count(sub.fecha) AS diasSeHanVendido, sub.num AS productos
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(fecha_venta) AS fecha, COUNT(*) AS num
    FROM productos
    GROUP BY DATE(fecha_venta)
) sub
GROUP BY sub.num
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me gusta trabajar bastante con tablas temporales.

Primero guardas tu primera consulta en la tabla `#temp1`

```
SELECT fecha_venta, COUNT(*) as productosvendidos into #temp1
FROM productos 
GROUP BY fecha_venta
```

Y luego hacemos consulta sobre esta tabla:

```
select count(fecha_venta) as repeticiones, productosvendidos
from #temp1
group by productosvendidos
```

Y ya lo tienes. Al finalizar es improtante limpiar la tabla temporal:

```
drop table #temp1
```